# Store files ordered by timestamp in Azure File Share

Tags: azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I have an application that writes files to Azure file share. But in Azure file share I see files are storing/inserting in alphabetical order. But I want them store/insert as per their insert timestamp. Is there any configuration or setting to keep the order of insertion in azure file share ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any configuration or setting to keep the order of insertion
> in azure file share ?

No, as such there is no setting to change the order in which the files are stored/displayed. They are always sorted alphabetically. Furthermore, there is no server-side sorting available.

If you want to sort the files by insertion date/time, you will need to name the files in such a way so that the insertion time is included in the file name e.g. `2022-01-29T10:00:00Z-file1.txt, 2022-01-29T10:01:00Z-file1.txt`.